# How to list all `dependencyManagment` in Maven?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I use some BOM dependencies in my Maven project, such as:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencyManagement>
```

Whenever I need to add a dependency, I want to know if that dependency has been declared in any `dependencyManagement` I imported, so that I don't need to specify version for it.

Now I'm doing that manually, go to the source of those BOM files to check, but sometimes one BOM imports other BOMs as well, for example: `spring-boot-dependencies` imports `netty-bom` and `jackson-bom`. So I want to know is there a way to list(flatten) all my `dependencyManagement`?

Comment: IntelliJ has gutter icons to the left of the editor - it would have an icon there if the dependency is declared in parent pom. Since we usually declare dependencyManagement in parent pom anyway, it should be a good indicator for you.

Comment: Initially, I didn't think IntelliJ picked up BOM dependencies, but after reading your comment I verified that it does. I added it to my answer as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best you can do with maven is `mvn help:effective-pom` and grep for the dependency in question. It will show you [the effective pom](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html), including the expanded BOM dependencyManagement.

Also, if you use an IDE like IntelliJ, it will show an "arrow up" symbol for managed dependencies, including those pulled in via BOM.

Comment: "mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose"
adds exact reference where the declaration is comming from